# Stop a particular <div> appearing on just one page

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering could you help me, we currently have an announcement banner across the top of all our webpages which I want to remain apart from one page. A couple of guys did a bit of work for me a put an announcement in which I can edit via Custome Content Type Manager on Wordpress.

In the Header.php the code is there and I'm not sure how to get it to stop appearing on a particular page, the id of the page I DONT want it on is 2664. The code is shown below:

```
<?php  
            $gathering_page = get_the_ID();
            if( ($gathering_page == 3001 || $gathering_page ==2664) && !(is_front_page()) ){ ?>
```

I'm not sure if the guys have tried to block it or what this code means.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: This may make it easier; I would like to make a div class disappear on the page named above. the div class is

```
        <div class="snippetHomeTop">
```

Comment: It would help to see what was after the `if` line. Is it including or excluding the banner there?

Comment: According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID. The get_the_ID() function return post's id, not page's id

Comment: have you considered just hiding the element in css? each WP page will be assigned unique body classes so targeting would be easy. Aside that, agreed with trueblueaussie. We don't know what happens after that conditional. But $gathering_page == 2664 means if the page IS equal to 2664. $gathering_page != 2664 would mean NOT page 2664.

Comment: I am trying to get this div to not appear on one particular page which has id 2664

  <div class="snippetHomeTop">

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I did wrong, but have you tried using the is page?

```
      <?php if (is_page('2664')) {
       // don´t show content for page ID 2664
       } else {
       // show content for other pages
       }?>
```

Good Luck